# Typescript error during inline fontWeight style in React

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to implement this css rule on a `td`

```
const boldText = {
    fontWeight: 'bold'
}

<td style={boldText}>Content</td>
```

But it's throwing the following error:

```
[ts]
Type '{ style: { fontWeight: string; }; children: string; }' is not assignable to type 'DetailedHTMLProps<TdHTMLAttributes<HTMLTableDataCellElement>, HTMLTableDataCellElement>'.
  Type '{ style: { fontWeight: string; }; children: string; }' is not assignable to type 'TdHTMLAttributes<HTMLTableDataCellElement>'.
    Types of property 'style' are incompatible.
      Type '{ fontWeight: string; }' is not assignable to type 'CSSProperties'.
        Types of property 'fontWeight' are incompatible.
          Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"bold" | "initial" | "inherit" | "unset" | "normal" | "bolder" | "lighter" | 100 | 200 | 300 | 40...'.
```

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Typescript can be awfuly silly sometimes. It's inferring the type of `fontWeight` as a string, even though it could narrow it to its exact literal. You can just cast it as itself to fix this:

```
const boldText = {
    fontWeight: 'bold' as 'bold'
}

<td style={boldText}>Content</td>
```

These days you can also use the new [`as const` declaration](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) at the end of your literals for the same effect:

```
const boldText = {
    fontWeight: 'bold'
} as const;

<td style={boldText}>Content</td>
```

And finally, you can always provide an explicit type to the object when you declare it:

```
const boldText: React.CSSProperties = {
    fontWeight: "bold"
};

<td style={boldText}>Content</td>
```

Comment: Weird thing is when I do `const warning = {
    color: 'blue',
};` it works just fine.

Comment: If you have many properties with the same issue, instead of fixing one by one you can also declare the style object as **any**: ```const boldText = { fontWeight: 'bold' } as any;```

Comment: This should not be the answer at all. Please use the type! Import CSSProperties from react or w/e and use it on the properties object.

Comment: @JustDave Feel free to click the 'edit' button and add that information to the answer. Although it is worth noting that using the type is likely better but may not always be practical depending on circumstance.

Answer (score 6):

Typescript sees `boldText` as a "normal" object, and so infers `boldText.fontWeight` as string:

```
const boldText = {
    fontWeight: 'bold' // <-- TS doesn't know more than this is a string
}
```

The code `<td style={boldText}>Content</td>` expects `CSSProperties`, so a string can't be assigned.

**To solve** the mismatch, you can tell Typescript the type of the object:

```
const boldText: CSSProperties = {
    fontWeight: 'bold'
}
```

### To be more precise:

- e.g. `color: '#ff0000'` would work, because `color` accepts values of type string.
- `fontWeight: 'bold'` doesn't work, although `fontWeight` accepts `"bold"`, because TS decides to use the type *string* before it knows about the context of CSS, and the type *string* is not the same as the type *"bold" | "bolder" | 100 | 200 | ...*:

```
const boldText = {
    fontWeight: 'bold'  // <-- TS makes it's decision for type 'string'
    color: '#ff0000'    // <-- TS makes it's decision for type 'string'
}

// TS doesn't complain about color, as color accepts NamedColor | string | ...
// TS only complains about fontWeight, as it accepts only "bold" | "bolder" | 100 | 200 | ...
const TD = <td style={boldText}>Content</td>
```

Answer (score 6):

Similar to [CRice's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48087031/1680301) but just a bit more generic:

```
type FontWeight = 'normal' | 'bold' | '100' | '200' | '300' | '400' | '500' | '600' | '700' | '800' | '900';

const boldText = {
   fontWeight: 'bold' as FontWeight;
}

<td style={boldText}>Content</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way around it is to use CSS Modules or Styles Components.

Also note, Typescript appears to only throw errors when defining CSS attributes that are originally hyphenated.

```js
//in component
<div style={styles.container}></div>

//down below
//works
const styles = {
  container: {
    'display': 'flex',
    'padding': '5%',
    'color': 'black'
  }
}

//doesn't work
const styles = {
  container: {
    'flex-basis': '50%',
    'flex-direction': 'column',
    'background-color': '#2A3A4D'
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

in react font weight should be a string ,

`fontWeight enum('normal', 'bold', '100', '200', '300', '400', '500', '600', '700', '800', '900')
Specifies font weight. The values 'normal' and 'bold' are supported for most fonts. Not all fonts have a variant for each of the numeric values, in that case the closest one is chosen.`

so you can choose like following

```
const boldText = {
  fontWeigth: '100'
}
```

or

```
const boldText = {
  fontWeight: 'bold'
}
```